# Joint probability distribution of correlated data points

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, deep-learning, likelihood

I have a query with respect to joint distributions.

Here, each output data point in $\mathbf{y}$ is conditionally independent given the inputs $\mathbf{x}$ and the mapping $f:\mathbf{x}\rightarrow \mathbf{y}$ (the task is basically to estimate the mapping $f$). Then the likelihood can be written as the product of the individual likelihood functions:$$p(\mathbf{y}|f,\mathbf{x})=\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(y_i|f,x_i)$$
However, if we now assume that the data points are $\textbf{not}$ independent, then how do we represent the likelihood.

I have difficulty in getting the right approach. How should I proceed?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify at least two more pieces of information: (1) the probability distribution over the set of possible $f$ (which, as a "mapping," evidently is some kind of stochastic process) and (2) the full probability distribution over $\mathbf x.$  This continues to assume $f$ and $\mathbf x$ are independent.

Comment: @whuber  I do not have any information about the distribution over the set of possible $f$ and neither any knowledge about the distribution over $\mathbf{x}$. The likelihood of the data is for a given input $\mathbf{x}$ and mapping $f$. In that case, how do we express the likelihood considering dependent data points.  Is there a general way?

Comment: The same principle applies: you must specify the conditional dependence structure of $\mathbf y;$ that is, the conditional joint probability of $\mathbf y.$

Comment: @whuber OK! I think I got the idea. Thanks a lot!!